# I need help at a register c# form

Tags: c#, mysql, phpmyadmin

In Visual Studio: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY''

In PHPMYADMIN: #1048 - Column 'firstname' cannot be null

I tried to search and find an answer but i didnt find.

PHPMYADMIN: INSERT INTO `users`(`firstname`, `lastname`, `email`, `username`, `password`) VALUES (@fn, @ln, @email, @usn, @pass)

Visual Studio:

```
        db.openConnection();
        if (command.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("ACCOUNT CREATED");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("ERROR");
        }
        db.closeConnection();
```

Comment: Why do you don' show us the command and how you fill it with ddata  and espially debuig the code and see what is in your first_name variable.  PHPmyadmin would understand your command if you set the seesion variables like @fn with some contenet

Answer (score 0):

From the error you are seeing in PHPMyAdmin, it seems like an issue in your database structure. Although I cannot be certain from the information posted, it appears that you have setup the id as a primary key with the intention that it be an auto increment field. Have you defined the field as auto increment?

```
ALTER TABLE users CHANGE COLUMN `id` `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
```

Where id is the name of you primary key field. This is usually the culprit of an error like `Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY`

If that does not help, are you able to post the structure of the table so we can have more information to try help you with this?